# Set focus on an edittext after using

Tags: java, android, focus, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` that recieves input and prints in on the screen. I need to find a way wherein after click submit or enter, the phone will focus on the `EditText`

I tried

```
txtJoke.setFocusable(true);
txtJoke.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
txtJoke.requestFocus();
```

and it doesn't work.. 
requestfocus works during onCreate..
I'm thinking of manually triggering a click an edittext..

Comment: requestFocus() worked for me during button click callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ...

```
Button newButton.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.onFocusChangeListener) {....}
```

to specify where will be the focus go next.

Comment: How do you specify the view that will receive the next focus here?